# Rewrite rule to return index.html in all subdirectories without change the url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I Have the next configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName projectsite.com
        ServerAlias projectsite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/project

 
        <Directory />
                 RewriteEngine On
               Options +FollowSymlinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all grant
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
                RewriteRule ^/?.+$ / [L]
        </Directory>
       
</VirtualHost>
```

The project manage all urls from the client, so, I only need to return the index.html file and I render the modules with javascript. It works ok but If the url matches with a folder then I am getting a 403 error "Forbidden". Instead of this, I need return the root index.html file either is the url matches with a directory name or not.

¿How can I do it ? I tried to find on internet but I didn't found something similar.

UPDATED:
how Dusan Bajic told me, I removed that line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and it resolved the first problem, but now the Rule is adding a slash at the final of the url,
If I have "site.com/reports" it changes to "site.com/reports/". I need to mantain the url without this slash. I think the problem is with the
next Rule:
 `RewriteRule ^/?.+$ / [L]`
But i don't know the correct way to make it

Comment: just remove the line with `!-d` :https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How @dusanBajic commented I had a rule that prevented what I need.
The rule is :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

This rule indicates that the rewrite rule only apply if the folder does not exists. So what I did was Remove that instruction and add the next rule `DirectorySlash Off` to prevent apache puts a slash at the final of the url.

The code left like this:

```
        <Directory />
                RewriteEngine On
                Options +FollowSymlinks
                DirectorySlash Off
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
                RewriteRule ^/?.+$ / [L]
        </Directory>
```